# Metric on the set of CDFs with finite p-th moment

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{F}_p$, $p \ge 1$, be the set of all cumulative distribution functions of real valued random variables whose $p$-th moment is finite.

I'm looking for a metric on $\mathcal{F}_p$ and tried to check the following candidate.

Define $$d(F,G):=\inf_{(X,Y)\in A}\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}$$ where $A$ is the set of all pairs $(X,Y)$ of random variables such that $F$ is the CDF of $X$ and $G$ is the CDF of $Y$.

Symmetry and positive definiteness are easy to check, but I have no idea how to assess whether the triangle inequality holds.

By what argument could I prove it?

Comment: Choose $(X,Y)$ such that $E[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}$ approaches $d(F,G)$. Choose $(T,Z)$ such that $E[|T-Z|^p]^{1/p}$ approaches $d(G,H)$. There exists $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ such that $(\xi,\eta)$ is distributed like $(X,Y)$ and $(\eta,\zeta)$ is distributed like $(T,Z)$. Consider $(\xi,\zeta)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How should I choose e.g. $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Such that $E[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant d(F,G)+\varepsilon$ with $X$ of CDF $F$ and $Y$ of CDF $G$.

Comment: Hm, that's what I thought, but I don't see how to do it. :/

Comment: Well, this is the *definition* of $d(F,G)$, no?

Comment: Sorry, I see that this is the definition. But I don't see for which random variables the infimum is taken. I assume that I need to choose specific random variables $X$ and $Y$? Furthermore, I still don't see whether this will lead to a metric or not. The problem explicitly asks to check if $d$ defines a metric, or to apply a little alteration to make it a metric instead. I've looked it up and could find that $d$ is called Wasserstein metric, so I guess it is indeed a metric, but the proof I found makes use of theorems I don't know and wouldn't want to use. Is there an elementary proof as well?

Comment: This is a metric allright. // To help me help you, you might want to mention the parts of my comment (which makes for a full proof, believe it or not...) you have problems with.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. You start by choosing a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ such that $E[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}$ approaches $d(F_X,G_Y)$, i.e. $E[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant d(F_X,G_Y)+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon \gt 0$. Do you mean by this that I have to construct specific random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: What is also not clear to me: In what sense should $E[|X-Y|^p]^{1/p}$ approach $d(F,G)$? I mean, I can imagine a sequence of random variables $(X_n,Y_n)$ such that $E[|X_n-Y_n|^p]^{1/p}$ approaches $d(F,G)$ for $n$ to $\infty$, but I suppose that's not what you mean?

Comment: *...that I have to construct specific random variables X and Y?* No, you know these exist by definition of $d(F,G)$ as an infimum. // *I can imagine a sequence...* Yes, this is exactly what the infimum gives you.

Comment: Ok, so I have sequences $(X_n,Y_n)$ and $(T_n,Z_n)$ of random variables such that $E[|X_n-Y_n|^p]^{1/p}$ converges to $d(F,G)$ and $E[|T_n-Z_n|^p]^{1/p}$ converges to $d(G,H)$. $(X,Y)$ and $(T,Z)$ are the limits of those sequences? How can I conclude their convergence from the convergence of $E[|X_n-Y_n|^p]^{1/p}$, $E[|T_n-Z_n|^p]^{1/p}$ respectively? Next, I need to find $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ such that $(\xi,\eta)$ has the distribution of $(X,Y)$ and $(\eta,\zeta)$ the same as $(T,Z)$? Again, I don't see why such $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ exists.

Comment: No convergence is needed (and none is guaranteed). Instead, one fixes $\varepsilon$ and one picks $(X,Y)$ and $(T,Z)$ as in my second comment. Since the marginals of $Y$ and $T$ coincide, it is a general result (often called "coupling") that $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ exist as in my first comment. Then $E[|\xi-\zeta|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant E[|\xi-\eta|^p]^{1/p}+E[|\eta-\zeta|^p]^{1/p}$ implies $d(F,H)\leqslant d(F,G)+d(G,H)+2\varepsilon$. QED.

Comment: Do you have a source where this "coupling" principle is explained in the form as used here? As for the rest: So for fixed $\epsilon \gt 0$ we pick $(X,Y)$ and $(T,Z)$ as stated above. Then we have $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ with $(\xi,\eta)$ distributed like $(X,Y)$ and $(\eta,\zeta)$ like $(T,Z)$. Now I need to understand why we have $$E[|\xi-\zeta|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant E[|\xi-\eta|^p]^{1/p}+E[|\eta-\zeta|^p]^{1/p},$$ from there it's clear.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see why we have $$E[|\xi-\zeta|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant E[|\xi-\eta|^p]^{1/p}+E[|\eta-\zeta|^p]^{1/p}.$$

Comment: T. Lindvall, Lectures on the coupling method (first chapter). // [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: Sadly, that particular book (and the other one referred to at Wikipedia) is checked out in our library. Intuitively, it makes sense that such a triple of random variables $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ must exist.

Comment: @Amarus: well, you do coupling directly here: in fact the $A$ is the set of all couplings of probability measures related to $F$ and $G$. Anyways, if you don't have an access to Lindvall's book, check out [Theorem 2.10 here](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/probability/lecturenotes/CouplingLectures.pdf) or check out "Coupling, Stationarity and Regeneration" in you library.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to start with a probability space for $(\xi,\eta) = (X,Y)$ and construct $\zeta$ there using the conditional probability (which is [regular](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427194/conditional-probability-is-not-a-probability-measure-but-it-does-satisfy-each-o/428153#428153) in your case)  of $P(Z|T)$.